# Spreadsheet: function to watch row for changes

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a spreadsheet function that can watch a row and update a cell with the current date when any cell in that row changes? If not for the entire row then perhaps just watch a single cell?

Comment: Working single cell onEdit answer on the following Web Applications thread; could be modified to watch an entire row I would think: http://goo.gl/ps3ZI5

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it, would be to use the `onEdit` trigger. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Besides that, you have to use extensive programming techniques to achieve your goal.

### Issue Tracker

See the following feature request on the issue tracker:  **[issue 200; onEdit: access original data](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=200)**.
If you vote, it might get introduced.

### Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067652

Answer (score -4):

Using Google Spreadsheets, you can use [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

Comment: Why don't you show us some code?