# Inventory Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons

I'm running Google sheets on a Windows laptop and using Google Chrome as my browser. I work in a clothing store and would like to make an inventory list that my coworkers can access and update (maybe using Google forms?). I would like to organize it with counts for each type of clothing we sell and would like for it to show the date and time that each section was last updated. For example, division 50 is pants and shorts and whenever someone posts a new count from that division I would like the other column to show who it was and when. If anyone knows how to do this I would really appreciate some help and advice.

Also, I would like my coworkers to be able to access and update the inventory list from their smartphones.

Comment: This is really broad, and really rather beyond the ken of this site. There are so many things you might do, or ways to do things, that there's no practical way to answer your question. Stack Exchange sites do better with questions about concrete, relatively small, issues that have direct, objectively correct answers. A question about why a particular function isn't giving the value you expect, would be one example. Remember, too, that we like questions and answers that will be useful to many more people than just the Asker.

Comment: @AlE. Thank you for the feedback, and I appreciate it. I'm new to the site and must have misunderstood the types of questions I should ask.

Comment: @AlE. Would it be a better question if I made it more clear that the only function I want help with is with creating a time stamp column that updates for each row when a value in said row is changed?

Comment: These sites are a bit different. The [tour] should be helpful.

Comment: That's a quite focused question that should be just fine, but I'm pretty sure it's also already been asked. Let me see if I can find the duplicate.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52314/354

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51558/354

Comment: This question is asking for something else, but the code provided in the question seems to be exactly what you're looking for: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94849/354

Comment: @AlE. Thank you for helping me, I think I actually found that post a few days ago. It seemed perfect but it didn't work for some reason. I may be doing it wrong though. I went into script editor, called the new project "Timestamp", and copy/pasted the code suggested into the script editor, but nothing Is happening. I can post a screenshot soon if that would help(and if I can even do that here).

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question. Reference the other question, share the code you used, and describe exactly what is (or isn't) happening.

Comment: @AlE. Okay thank you, I might do that after work tonight. Is it cool if I keep this question up in the meantime though? I like the resources you posted and still have more reading to do.

Comment: You might also just look at AirTable which is a simple cloud database that works with iOS and has version control letting you know who updated the values last. That may be a lot easier than trying to set up a Google Sheet. If you're using Square, you can also just turn on Inventory Management.

Comment: @Sun This looks like a cool idea! I'm going to download it and I'll let you know if it works! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad I understood it and had a solution already based on previous need.

Comment: @Sun Thank you so much. Your idea worked out great by the way, I used air table and my boss was really happy! I'll try to upvote your response but I think my rep is to low for it to do anything :/

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the down votes. Ask other questions in the future! Glad to help and recommend.

Comment: @Sun Thanks! I really appreciate the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Google Sheet that looks at latest fuel entry for vehicles and another spreadsheet takes the latest entry per vehicle, and shows the number. You could likely use it for your Inventory since the concept is the same. Your folks enter via Google Forms and latest entry per item is what shows up on a different sheet. [Readings & Summary sheet](http://ttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV6TC6Fv085es-dxjqo1AEITGBXNzHlPHWak73AY0YI/edit?usp=sharing) and the [Actual Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gm9W_77AKn8pL3S0Ya3WgCCqein0C8wMY1f1TFH8J7o/edit?usp=sharing)

Enter the values you want for Inventory updates here (in my example odometer reading):
[image]

Then this sheets shows the latest Max odometer reading by vehicle. For you, you'd want max transaction date for an item and get the count and person who entered that count.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it might work too! I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Your Airtable idea is the one that worked but I can't vote on the comment so I'm gonna mark this as the best answer! Hopefully that at least gives you credit! Thanks again, you totally saved the day!